# Jquery CSS fadeOut animation not working when menu close

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my simple approach for a dropdown menu. When I click to open a menu, it opens with an amination. But I want to add another animation when It will be closed. I tried in many ways, But not working. Why? Somebody, please assist me. When It closes, it directly disappears. No animation is working. Why?

```
    body {
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-btn {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        left: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .dropdown-btn__icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
        display: none;
        min-width: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform-origin: top right;
        animation: dropdown-menu-open 0.3s forwards;
    }

    .dropdown-menu__list {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-menu__list li {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu__list a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 16px;
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 16px;
    }

    @keyframes dropdown-menu-open {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale(0, 0);
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
    }

    .dropdown--open .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-menu__list {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 03s ease;
    }

    .dropdown-menu__list--hidden {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 03s ease;
    }

    #asma {
        float: right! important;
    }
```

```
<span id="asma">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-btn mi-ripple mi-ripple-dark">
            <div class="dropdown-btn__icon"> &equiv; </div>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu__list">
                <li class="mi-ripple mi-ripple-dark"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="mi-ripple mi-ripple-dark"><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
                <li class="mi-ripple mi-ripple-dark"><a href="#">Createanewbjsbsjshsbsticket</a></li>      
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>




$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown--open');
    if ($('.dropdown').hasClass('dropdown--open')) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
    } else {
      $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('dropdown-menu__list--hidden');
      });
    }
  });

  $(document).on('touchstart click', function(event) {
    if (!$('.dropdown').is(event.target) && $('.dropdown').has(event.target).length === 0) {
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown--open');
      $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).addClass('dropdown-menu__list--hidden');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The jquery fadeOut effect not working. What I can do now? How to add it?

Comment: Can anybody help me....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, or even CSS `animation` at all. Instead, you can achieve the same effect using CSS `transition`.
Updated script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown--open');
  });

  $(document).on('touchstart click', function(event) {
    if (!$('.dropdown').is(event.target) && $('.dropdown').has(event.target).length === 0) {
     $('.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown--open');
    }
  });
});
```

Updated styles:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;     <--- here is the trick
  transform: scale(0);                  <---
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  min-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.dropdown.dropdown--open .dropdown-menu {
  transform: scale(1);                  <---
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/cheack/kd92r8g0/42/

Update: If you want to apply a different transition when closing, simply add another transition and add a delay to the first one.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s;   <--- last 0.3s is a delay for a scaling (to fade out first, then scale down)
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.dropdown.dropdown--open .dropdown-menu {
  transform: scale(1); 
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: @cheak You awesome man. But Can I just add a fadeOut effect only for just close time ? Open animation will same, but close animation will fadeOut. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Md.Ibrahim sure, see https://jsfiddle.net/cheack/kd92r8g0/63/

Comment: @cheak Thanks Brother. I'm Fully satisfied.